# Can I use a Chi Squared test if one participant contributes more than once to the same cell

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, proportion

I have an experiment that can be thought of in this manner:

I have two rooms and in each room I have two buttons: one red and one blue. One of the rooms is painted blue and the other is painted red. I send 2000 people through the rooms, 1000 each, and they press a button.

I want to test if there is a difference in the proportion of people pushing the red or blue buttons. The null hypothesis being that both rooms will have the same ratio of red to blue, the alternate being that the colour of the room alters the proportions in some way.

I can construct a contingency table of the four possibilities and perform a chi-squared test to determine if the two rooms are significantly different.

My question is, can I still do this if one of the participants might push a button more than once? Because of the way the experiment is set up, I know that they will not push different buttons but may push the same button any number of times.

Comment: Since a single aberrant individual could account for any pattern you could possibly observe in the table, you are asking whether it's possible to distinguish that situation from one in which all participants follow the rules but there are real differences in proportions.  It looks obvious that making such a distinction is impossible: the data cannot discriminate between the two scenarios.  I wonder whether you have successfully abstracted the essential characteristics of your experiment in this description.

Comment: I think you can not do that if a person pushes a button twice except if both of these pushes are independent but that is  not the case if the same person Always pushes the same button.